# I dont know what ive done wrong, , i have followed a guide, it could be a outdated software issue or something?

Tags: python, pygame

Please someone figure out why I'm dumb and this no worky
I've tried to change the main loop around e.g. removing some lines, idk
I made the window random because I was bored
the main issue I have is the window instantly opening then closing, I don't know why this happens, pls help :)

```
import pygame
import random

random1 = (random.randint(1, 2000))
random2 = (random.randint(1,2000))
width, height = random1, random2
fps = 60
red = (255, 0, 0)

window = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("i don't know what im doing")

man_character = pygame.image.load('mancharacter.jpg')


def draw_window():
    window.fill(red)
    window.blit('mancharacter.jpg')
    window.blit('potato.PNG')
    pygame.display.update()

def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    pizza = True
    while pizza:
        clock.tick(fps)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.Quit():
                pizza = False
        draw_window()
    pygame.Quit()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. "I'm dumb and this no worky" is _never_ an acceptable problem statement.

Comment: It doesn't look like you ever call `main()`. Is there more to this code somewhere?

Comment: Where did you get the example of the code, you had to have some.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this part of code :

```py
def main():
    #[...]
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.Quit():
             pizza = False
        draw_window()
    pygame.Quit()
```

Pygame doesn't have any attribute 'Quit', so it should be somewhat like this :

```py
def main():
    #[...]
    while pizza:
        clock.tick(fps)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: #Remove the parentheses and capitalise the word
                pizza = False
        draw_window()
    pygame.quit() #quit not Quit
```

This should probably work

```py
import pygame
import random

random1 = (random.randint(1, 2000))
random2 = (random.randint(1,2000))
width, height = random1, random2
fps = 60
red = (255, 0, 0)

window = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("i don't know what im doing")

man_character = pygame.image.load('mancharacter.jpg')


def draw_window():
    window.fill(red)
    window.blit('mancharacter.jpg')
    window.blit('potato.PNG')
    pygame.display.update()

def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    pizza = True
    while pizza:
        clock.tick(fps)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pizza = False
        draw_window()
    pygame.quit()

main() #You need to call this function
```